# Fetch paid Amount value from iframe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, javascript

```
   if(ScenarioName.equals("MoveinwithVantivCard")) {

     driver.findElement(By.id("btnsave")).click();
  // driver.switchTo().frame("paymentIFrame");
     driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("paymentIFrame")));
     driver.findElement(By.id("cardNumber")).sendKeys("5499990123456781");
     driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    String paid=driver.findElement(By.id("//h3[@id='paidamount']")).getText();
    System.out.println(paid);

      }
```

Here I am trying to do Credit card Payment After that i am trying to fetch 
 that paid amount value which is in frame but it is not happening it waits for long 
 time any help would be appreciated

Comment: [How to switch to iframe in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687149/how-to-switch-to-iframe-in-selenium)

Comment: May be you frame disappear once you submit the details. it require debugging

Comment: when i inspect that element it is displaying current iframe Id

Answer (score 0):

If the amount is appearing in an iframe, first you need to switch to that iframe by its id before you fetch the amount. Once you are done with the iframe, return to the main window.

```
// to switch to the iframe by iframe id
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
//get the paid amount here once done switch to main window as below.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); when i debug it stops at that defaultcontent

Comment: reasons might be numerous, although try using  `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();`